int.to_bytes for integer 288 does not display the second byte(0x20) of 0x0120
The goal is to construct a byte array that is used for sending ModBus commands. The initial array is populated with 0x05 0x04(device address five, read) and we are calculating the address next.
async def requestErrorLogNumber(blueClient, errorLogNum):
global requestedState

# Create the ModBus write message
# We will write to device one, address zero and then add the cycle number we want to write
modbusBytes = READ_DEVICE_5
address = 256 + (errorLogNum*32)

# Convert the number into bytes to add to the byte array
byte_address = address.to_bytes(length=2, byteorder='big')
modbusBytes += byte_address

size = 8
readSize = size.to_bytes(length=2, byteorder='big')
modbusBytes += readSize

# Calculate the CRC for this ModBus packet
headerCRC = crccheck.crc.Crc16Modbus()
headerCRC.process(modbusBytes)
tempCrc = headerCRC.final()

The address is calculated to a value of 288, but the address.to_bytes results in a singular byte value of 0x01(instead of the correct value of 0x01 0x20). The next use of to_bytes(where we are setting the ModBus read length of 8) works correctly by returning 0x00 0x08. Even using (288).to_bytes(length=2, byteorder='big') returns a single byte value of 0x01. Any idea what is incorrect?


The types you're looking at are what Python calls "bytestrings". As the name implies, they behave like strings in many respects: 'hello'.encode('utf-8') renders as b'hello', not as b'\x68\x65\x6c\x6f'; only characters that aren't printable as ASCII get rendered to hex escapes. It's always been that way ever since they were first introduced with Python 3.0 (and when they existed as just "strings" in Python 2).

Thanks. I've always used them in serial communications and the LiClipse variable renderings always irked me(you can't tell the debugger to show it as hex.) I don't use python enough to have pieced together why it displayed that way. Thanks to everyone for all the help.

You probably can get the debugger to show hex, since it says “add new expression”. Try adding “modbusBytes.hex()”

bytes display ASCII characters for bytes 32-126 (printable ASCII).  32 is a space.  b'\x01 ' is the bytes 1 and 32.
You may want to look at the struct module:
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('>HH', 288, 8)  # pack two big-endian unsigned 16-bit values
b'\x01 \x00\x08'
>>> struct.pack('>HH', 288, 8).hex(' ')  # display as a hex string
'01 20 00 08'
>>> list(struct.pack('>HH', 288, 8))  # display as integers
[1, 32, 0, 8]
>>> struct.pack('>BBHH', 5, 4, 288, 8)  # build your modbusBytes value
b'\x05\x04\x01 \x00\x08'


Not sure why this is marked as a typo problem as there are no typo's. It is a understanding issue. When you define the variable it is defined as bytearray, not bytestring. This question was very helpful for me.

@lynnejohn, ..."or resolved in a way unlikely to help future readers". With a different title this might have stayed open, but it's unlikely that the next person to be surprised by how bytestrings render will be able to find "int to bytes for integer 288 does not work" in their search results and recognize it as relevant. Without work on the question to make it searchable by and recognizable as relevant to folks with the same underlying issue, the people who need it won't be able to find it, so the resolution is not likely to be helpful to future readers.

@lynnejohn, (...feel free to ping me if you do edit towards that end and want a reopen vote).

I did edit the title and would like to reopen but I found no simple way to ping you.

If you reply to someone, you can add @ to notify them if they've already been involved in the question or answer, by commenting or editing.
